# Error: (HTTP code 500) server error - failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed

Tags: docker

Previously, I had built this Docker image on my Ubuntu machine, and it worked just fine. However, now when I try to pull this image and run the container on my Windows host machine, it gives me this error. I think this has something to do with the Nvidia-container toolkit, but I have no idea. Can somebody help me to fix this? The error is as follows:

```bash
Error: (HTTP code 500) server error - failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error running hook #0: error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: Auto-detected mode as 'legacy' nvidia-container-cli: mount error: file creation failed: /var/lib/docker/overlay2/33324a268eb0f46f63965ba19e71701131ad859579803bb3db742f3b3fe0a82d/merged/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-ml.so.1: file exists: unknown
```

The command I used for running the container is:

```bash
docker run  --gpus all -it -p 8000:8000 <myusername/<image_name>:latest-gpu
```